# Excel if with nested functions possible?

Tags: excel, function, if-statement, sum

I have a spreadsheet I'm trying to calculate fees and such with but instead of having 10 columns for calculating I want to condense it.

Can I input something like this in excel and get it to work? It's giving me errors right now.

```
=IF((u3*0.12)<1, "1", (=sumproduct(u3*0.12)+u3))
```

- The value in `u3` is a sum of 4 other rows
- `U3` is a sum of costs.
- I need `12%` of the costs of `u3` and if it's less than 1, I need the
  `u3` `sum + 1`.  If the value `u3*0.12` is `>1` I want the value
  `u3+(u3*0.12)` printed.

Sorry if I'm being redundant, I just want this thing to work

Comment: I think you are overthinking this one. `sumproduct()` is an odd choice here since you already know that you want `(u3*.12) + u3` I can't imagine what benefit you would gain wrapping that in sumproduct. Furthermore, formulas inside of formulas should not contain their own `=` sign.

Comment: thank you, i'll remember that next time i need to merge formulas! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Formula has some errors in it. But what you are wanting to do is completely possible.

The quick answer is yes you can nest formulas inside of formulas. I do not know how many levels you can go, but I have written some fairly complex ones myself, so they can go deep.

For what you have there change it to:

```
=If((U3*.12)<1,U3+1,SUM((U3*.12)+U3))
```

This says If 12% of U3 is less than one then this cells value is U3+1. However if 12% of U3 is greater than 1 then this cells value is 12% of U3 + U3

Comment: that `Sum()` is superfluous. There's nothing being summed there. It's like writing `Sum(5)`.

Answer (score 1):

> <sub>i need 12% of the costs of u3 and if it's less than 1, i need the u3 sum + 1. if the value u3*0.12 is >1 i want the value u3+(u3*0.12)</sub>

Try,

```
=if(u3<8.333, sum(1, u3), u3*1.12))
'alternate maths interpretation
=max(1, u3*0.12)+u3
```

Comment: Why the 8.3333?

Comment: `If((U3*0.12)<1, ...` and if(U3<8,333, ... ` are the same thing.

Comment: I see.. You are right. For some reason I'm having a really hard time wrapping my head around, but obviously 1 is .12 of 8.333. I think I need more sleep.

Comment: And your second mathed up solution is a thing of beauty. This deserves the "Accepted" answer.